# Substituting values in an RDD based on keys located in another RDD

Tags: dictionary, apache-spark, substitution

How can I assign/map values in an RDD based on keys in another RDD

e.g. Starting from:

```scala
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "A"), (2, "B")))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A", "B"), ("B", "B"), ("B", "A")))
```

How can I get something like this?

```
(1,2)(2,2)(2,1)
```

Comment: Are both RDDs huge? Do they fit in your driver?

Comment: rdd1 is a couple of GB but rdd2 is huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast the rdd1 as a lookup table (like a dictionary) and then use the broadcasted lookup table in rdd2 map

```
rdd1_local = sc.parallelize([(1,"A"),(2,"B")]).map(lambda x:(x[1],x[0])).collectAsMap()
rdd1_broadcast = sc.broadcast(rdd1_local)
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([("A", "B"), ("B", "B"), ("B", "A")])
rdd2.map(lambda x:(rdd1_broadcast.value[x[0]],rdd1_broadcast.value[x[1]])).take(2)
```

Comment: hey what is the purpose of the take(2)?

Answer (score 0):

Scala version:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, "A"), (2, "B")))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("A", "B"), ("B", "B"), ("B", "A")))

val rdd1_broadcast = sc.broadcast(rdd1.map(x=>(x._2,x._1)).collectAsMap())
val resultRDD = rdd2.map{x=> (rdd1_broadcast.value(x._1),rdd1_broadcast.value(x._2))}
```